# Is there a way to export Google bookmarks to another app?

Tags: firefox-for-android, bookmarks

I currently switched to firefox and would like to keep my Chrome bookmarks, but I can't find a way. Also I'm looking for a bookmarks editor/organizer. Are there any practical solution? I can't find any on the net easily.

Comment: Are your Chrome bookmarks synced to Google?  It might be easier to do this on a PC.  Start Firefox, run the [import wizard](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/import-bookmarks-google-chrome) to import Chrome bookmarks, set up [Firefox Sync](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-set-up-firefox-sync) on both desktop and mobile app, and you should be good to go.